# how to call soap webservice with large xml file as a parameter in android java

Tags: android, xml, soap, ksoap2, uploading

I am successfully  sending string and int to soap but not xml
SOAPAction:

```
"iReceiver/XPL-CIMS-iReceiver-RecordIssuesData" 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <XPL-CIMS-iReceiver-RecordIssuesData xmlns="iReceiver">
      <A_iStaffDId>int</A_iStaffDId>
      <A_strGUID>string</A_strGUID>
      <dsIssues>
        <xsd:schema>schema</xsd:schema>xml</dsIssues>
    </XPL-CIMS-iReceiver-RecordIssuesData>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am new to stackoverflow.please help me thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

use the below method to convert it to xml and call it this way :
Document document = XMLfromString(Str);

then parse it this way

NodeList node = document.getElementsByTagName("firsttag") and send it

public Document XMLfromString(String v) {

```
    Document doc = null;

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(v));
        doc = db.parse(is);

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        System.out.println("Wrong XML file structure: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return doc;

}
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply.i have to send so many elements in <dsIssue> issue tag like <dsIssue><name>rk</name> <number>15245</> <age>23</age> etc. </dsIssue> server side they are getting as a dataset object. how can i send .please explain clearly.